# Can't seem to trigger scroll event on the body element in react

Tags: reactjs

//code snippets

```
const [bodyPosition, setBodyPosition] = useState(0)
  useEffect(()=>{
    let body = document.querySelector("body")
    console.log(body)
    body?.addEventListener("scroll", getBodyScrollPosition)

    return body?.removeEventListener("scroll", getBodyScrollPosition)
  },[])
  function getBodyScrollPosition(){
    console.log("body scrolled", bodyPosition)
    setBodyPosition((state)=>state + 1)
  }
```

The getBodyScrollPosition doesn't get called even after scrolling

**Note** this react typescript code

*code can be seen here*
https://github.com/merhmood/merhmood.github.io/blob/master/src/App.tsx

Comment: What is the purpose you want to achieve with this piece of code?

Comment: Get the scroll position of the page

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", getBodyScrollPosition)
```

try to use `window`. if you want to use `body`, you should give body a css style, such as

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: scroll event isn't trigger, i think the get scroll position function isn't called, but i don't know why

Comment: I clone the repo, and it works fine when i replace body with window

Comment: can share me the code

Comment: i only replace body with window, and it can print 'body scrolled' in the console

Comment: like this window.addEventListener("scroll", getBodyScrollPosition)

Comment: yes, i only change this.

Comment: tried it but the console isn't showing the body scrolled message

Comment: what version of react are using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247246/discussion-between-zer0321-and-mahmud-suberu).